# Does an update to the datagrid ItemSource kick the user out of editing mode?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using a `datagrid` that shows a combination of read only display information and user editable information on the same row.  We use a backing object( `ItemSource` with the update mode set to `twoway`

I've noticed that when I'm in editing mode in a cell, occasionally I'll be kicked out of editing mode before I've hit enter to apply my change.  I'm guessing that the culprit is another cell updating programatically.

Can anyone confirm if this is the regular wpf behaviour and if so is there something I can do to prevent the datagrid from exiting editing mode?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked it. *The collection changes doesn't break the edit mode*.

I have created a test project, and add items to a `Wpf 4.0`'s `DataGrid` in Background, and this doesn't break the edit mode in the DataGrid. *The edit mode is broken when the DataGrid lose the focus.* So probably that is what happens in your case.

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        timer.Tick += (t, a) => DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(ExecuteAddPersonCommand);
        timer.Start();
```

This examples uses `MvvmLight Toolkit`.

Hope this helps.